# VBA Encountering an Overflow error and I cant figure out how to fix it. The data types dont exceed there value , so I am stumped

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

This is the table i am working with..

[image]

Im Using VBA to output the results to look like this.

[image]

It looks like the code is working correctly, but im still getting the overflow error.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried adjusting all Data Types and making sure the values are not exceeding the expected data type. The weird part is, the code seems to be completing but im still getting the error.

```
Sub TestData()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim Ticker As String
    Dim totalVolume As Double
    Dim open_price As Double
    Dim high_price As Double
    Dim low_price As Double
    Dim close_price As Double
    Dim yearly_change As Double
    Dim percent_change As Double
    Dim summary_row As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    summary_row = 2 
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        
        If Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            
            Cells(summary_row, 9).Value = Ticker
            Cells(summary_row, 10).Value = yearly_change
            Cells(summary_row, 11).Value = percent_change
            Cells(summary_row, 12).Value = totalVolume

            totalVolume = 0
            summary_row = summary_row + 1
        End If
        
        totalVolume = totalVolume + Cells(i, 7).Value
        
        Ticker = Cells(i, 1).Value
        
        If i = 2 Or Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then
            open_price = Cells(i, 3).Value
        End If
        
        close_price = Cells(i, 6).Value
        
        If i = lastRow Or Cells(i, 1).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 1).Value Then
            yearly_change = close_price - open_price
            percent_change = yearly_change / open_price
        End If
    Next i
    
    Cells(summary_row, 9).Value = Ticker
    Cells(summary_row, 10).Value = yearly_change
    Cells(summary_row, 11).Value = percent_change
    Cells(summary_row, 12).Value = totalVolume
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: It doesn't tell me. Usually VBA doesn't show an error line....would be helpful if it did.

Comment: If you provide your data in text format (optimally formatted as a markdown table), it may be easier to help.

Comment: Usually VBA let's you interrupt the code when the error occurs. You could add something like `On Error GoTo ErrHandler` before your for loop with `ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & " : " & Err.Description, vbCritical` after your for loop. That should allow you to check what the variable values are at the time of the error. Maybe there's a 0 in the 3rd column? Since you're dividing yearly_change with open_price

Comment: What *exactly* happens when you run your code?  You say it completes successfully, so where is the error coming up?  Is there no "Debug" button when you get the error message?