# dont know how to fix

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

Getting a run time error 1004 and dont understand what that means or how to fix it.

fairly new to the world of coding taking a class in coding while they dont explain anything that well to the majority of newbies doing coding.

```
Sub StockAnalysis():
   
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
       
       Dim Ticker As String
       Dim YearlyChange As Double
       Dim PercentChange As Double
       Dim TotalVolume As Double
       Dim LastRow As Long
       Dim SummaryRow As Long
       Dim OpeningPrice As Double
       Dim ClosingPrice As Double
       
       ws.Cells(1, 9).Value = "Ticker"
       ws.Cells(1, 10).Value = "Yearly Change"
       ws.Cells(1, 11).Value = "Percent Change"
       ws.Cells(1, 12).Value = "Total Stock Volume"
       
       LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
       
       SummaryRow = 2
       
       For i = 2 To LastRow
           
           If ws.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value <> ws.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
               
               Ticker = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
               OpeningPrice = ws.Cells(i, 3).Value
               ClosingPrice = ws.Cells(i, 6).Value
               YearlyChange = ClosingPrice - OpeningPrice
               
               If OpeningPrice <> 0 Then
                   PercentChange = (YearlyChange / OpeningPrice) * 100
               Else
                   PercentChange = 0
               End If
               
               ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 9).Value = Ticker
               ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 10).Value = YearlyChange
               ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 11).Value = PercentChange
               ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i - TotalVolume + 1, 7), ws.Cells(i, 7)))
               
               ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 11).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
               
               If YearlyChange > 0 Then
                   ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
               ElseIf YearlyChange < 0 Then
                   ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 10).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
               End If
               
               SummaryRow = SummaryRow + 1
               TotalVolume = 0
           End If
           
           TotalVolume = TotalVolume + ws.Cells(i, 7).Value
       Next i
       
       ' Find the maximum percent increase
       Dim MaxPercentIncrease As Double
       Dim MaxPercentTicker As String
       
       MaxPercentIncrease = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("K2:K" & SummaryRow))
       MaxPercentTicker = ws.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxPercentIncrease, ws.Range("K2:K" & SummaryRow), 0) + 1, 9).Value
       ws.Cells(2, 16).Value = MaxPercentTicker
       ws.Cells(2, 17).Value = MaxPercentIncrease
       ws.Cells(2, 17).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
       
       ' Find the maximum percent decrease
       Dim MaxPercentDecrease As Double
       Dim MaxPercentDecreaseTicker As String
       
      MaxPercentDecrease = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws.Range("K2:K" & SummaryRow))
       MaxPercentDecreaseTicker = ws.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxPercentDecrease, ws.Range("K2:K" & SummaryRow), 0) + 1, 9).Value
       ws.Cells(3, 16).Value = MaxPercentDecreaseTicker
       ws.Cells(3, 17).Value = MaxPercentDecrease
       ws.Cells(3, 17).NumberFormat = "0.00%"
       
       ' Find the stock with the greatest total volume
       Dim MaxTotalVolume As Double
       Dim MaxTotalVolumeTicker As String
       
       MaxTotalVolume = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws.Range("L2:L" & SummaryRow))
       MaxTotalVolumeTicker = ws.Cells(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxTotalVolume, ws.Range("L2:L" & SummaryRow), 0) + 1, 9).Value
       ws.Cells(4, 16).Value = MaxTotalVolumeTicker
       ws.Cells(4, 17).Value = MaxTotalVolume
       
   Next ws

End Sub
```

ran the code in vba and it does not work, dont have a large knowledge base to work off as i am very new to this

Comment: At which line do you get the error?

Comment: ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i - TotalVolume + 1, 7), ws.Cells(i, 7)))

Comment: Is this the same exercise as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76532320) ?

Answer (score 1):

The line `ws.Cells(SummaryRow, 12).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ws.Range(ws.Cells(i - TotalVolume + 1, 7), ws.Cells(i, 7)))` contains the following expression: `i - TotalVolume + 1`, which is used as a row index, so it should be a positive integer. However, as far as I understand the logic of your code, `TotalVolume` will contain a relatively big, possibly non-integer number, therefore the mentioned expression will be negative, and you can't use negative numbers in `.Cells`.

Comment: yeah i think so

Comment: ok so how can i fix it

Comment: these are what needs to happen
ticker symbol
Yearly change from the opening price at the beginning of a year to the closing price
percentage change from the opening price at the beginning of a given year to the closing price at the end of that year.
total stock volume of the stock.
Add functionality to your script to return the stock with the "Greatest % increase", "Greatest % decrease", and "Greatest total volume". The solution should match the following image:
Make the appropriate adjustments to your VBA script to enable it to run on every worksheet (that is, every year) at once.